# Can I use PowerShell to write a WebService?

Tags: web-services, powershell

Maybe I am using the wrong words to search google for this. But all i come up with is how to use .Net and C# on how to write a webservice. I know there is New-WebServiceProxy but I really would like to offer a service not consume it.

There reason I would like to use PowerShell is because I would like to progress as quickly as possible and it's the language i am currently most familiar with. Also the WebService should only offer very basic functions.

Any input on this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to execute PowerShell in your web service?

Comment: Interesting reading: http://powershill.blogspot.it/2011/08/exposing-powershell-as-web-service.html

Comment: Yes, I think @CB.'s link is the way to go. I had worked on a project like that before to host PowerShell runspace at the server side, and run script corresponding to client requests.

Comment: Have you looked at PipeWorks?  http://powershellpipeworks.com/

Comment: In addition to the previous comments it may be worth looking at this http://www.powershellserver.com/overview/web/

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to write powershell that accepts and returns HTTP messages without IIS. Is that correct? I've been searching for the same thing - just a simple stub that I can use to test REST clients. (BTW none of the posted links address this). If your objective is to get a web service running easily, it actually will most likely be easiest if you _do_ use C# and IIS

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be "/n software" PowerShellServer http://www.powershellserver.com/overview/web